# WCF throws SfxServerDidNotReply Error

Tags: wcf, silverlight, nettcpbinding

We are working on a Silverlight 4/5 application which communicates with the server through a NetTcp WCF service, hosted by windows service.

On some occasions we get an **SfxServerDidNotReply** error

This is barely documented online. People who experienced the same error haven't posted any answer anywhere.

Here is an [MSDN Thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/cb053d34-4418-4575-9053-1ce0139fc15e) that gives no answer.

We can also find a reference in this [ServiceChannel.cs class](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/WCF/WCF/3@5@30729@1/untmp/Orcas/SP/ndp/cdf/src/WCF/ServiceModel).
But this code seems to throw the exception only when the channel is twoway, which is not the case for us.

Also, this error happens client side, monitoring the service server-side shows nothing.

Any idea? Some WCF expert here?

Comment: Changing the endpoint from nettcp to http seems to remove the problem, hard to tell since the error does not show up consistently. I will be able to give a better answer soon.

Comment: How did u get on with this issue? Having a similar problem... :-/

Comment: The answer is sad, we are now running over HTTP endpoint and we haven't seen this exact error message since then. If you find the underlying reason behind this error message, please answer here.

Comment: Thanks for replying, yes will do. I'm already using HTTP. Investigations so far suggest a proxy server timing out connections after 2 minutes. Will report back

Comment: Experiencing the same problem but only after the server wcf app was moved to a different (external) server. Suggests the problem is at network level.